# SwipeRefreshLayout swipe down scrollview with progress bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        /*
        Something......
        */

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I want to swipe down my scrollview with progress bar.
Like left one.
How can i do this ?
[image: Swipe Down]

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can just put the androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout inside of the ScrollView